# Java Android - tag pictrues from camera roll to add to quiz

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am creating a user generated quiz app. The user should be able to select pictures from their camera roll which they can label and add them to a quiz of their choice.For example there will be a quiz called guess the family member where the pictures that the user has uploaded will be used.

so far I have been able to allow the user to select a picture from their camera roll and display it on screen however I am unsure how I could label the picures and add them to a specific quiz.

would appreciate if anyone could help or give me some guidance.

```
public class Editquizz extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_editquizz);
        FloatingActionButton button = findViewById(R.id.Uploadbtn);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 3);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null ){
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            imageView.setImageURI(selectedImage);

        }
    }


    public void onClickHandler12(View view){
        Intent myIntenet = new Intent(Editquizz.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntenet);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `EditText` to your layout and use that to label the image.
That does depend on how you are storing the quiz, but adding a string for the label should be simple.

Quiz:

`String url/uri = "https://...";`

`String label = editText.getText().toString();`

One way to store the quiz could be with `SharedPreferences`

`SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

`prefs.edit().putString("quiz1", url + ";" + label).apply();`

and just retrieve it with

```
String quiz1 = prefs.getString("quiz1", "");

if (!quiz1.isEmpty()) {
   String[] split = quiz1.split(";");
   String url = "";
   String name = "";
   if (split.length >= 1) {
      url = split[0];
   }
   if (split.length >= 2) {
      name = split[1];
   }
}
```

Or you can save it using sqlite

Room:

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

GreenDAO:

https://greenrobot.org/greendao/